# Why is the response to gapi.client.drive.realtime.get empty?

Tags: google-drive-api

Below is a page that succesfully authenticates, then tries to use the drive.realtime.get method to get a JSON export of an existing realtime document in three ways. The results of the console.log calls are shown inline in comments.

The file with id 'EXISTING-FILE-ID' exists and has had content added using the realtime api. I am able to get the JSON exported data in a browser at
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/EXISTING-FILE-ID/realtime?access_token=VALID-ACCESS-TOKEN which returns

`{"appId":"CLIENT-ID","revision":10,"data":{"id":"root","type":"Map","value":{"blah":{"json":"anything"},"key":{"json":"val"},"key2":{"json":"val2"}}}}`

However, in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, the response to gapi.client.drive.realtime.get and gapi.client.rpcRequest is always empty: `{"result":{}}`.

In Chrome and Firefox, the body of the response to gapi.client.request is a string of characters that partially changes when the content of the document is changed with the realtime api. This may be some gzipped content (response headers include {content-encoding: "gzip"}, but I haven't been able to gunzip it. The etag in the response header also changes when the document changes.

In Safari, the gapi.client.request response body contains the same string of characters as on Chrome and Firefox (eyJH...) but the correct contents of the exported document are shown in the console log, the same as when I use a browser window with the googleapis.com url.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var fileId = 'EXISTING-FILE-ID';
    var start = function() {
      // load apis (then call authorize)
      gapi.load('auth:client,drive-realtime', function() {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
          authorize();
        });
      });
    };
    // authorize with drive scope
    var authorize = function() {
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        'client_id': 'CLIENT-ID',
        'scope': ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                  'openid'],
        'immediate': true
      }, function() {
        realtimeget(fileId);
      });
    };
    // try to get realtime document export in 3 different ways
    var realtimeget = function(id) {
      gapi.client.drive.realtime.get({
        'fileId': id
      }).execute(function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));
        // {"0":{"result":{}},"1":"[\n {\n  \"id\": \"gapiRpc\",\n  \"result\": {}\n }\n]\n"} 
      });
      gapi.client.rpcRequest('drive.realtime.get', 'v2', {
        'fileId': id
      }).execute(function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));
        // {"0":{"result":{}},"1":"[\n {\n  \"id\": \"gapiRpc\",\n  \"result\": {}\n }\n]\n"} 
      });
      gapi.client.request({
        'path': '/drive/v2/files/' + id + '/realtime',
        'method': 'GET',
      }).execute(function() {
        console.log('gapi.client.request:');
        console.log(arguments[0]);
        // false
        console.log(arguments[1]);
        // {"gapiRequest":{"data":{"body":"eyJhcHBJZCI6IjEwNjY4MTY3MjA5NzQiLCJyZXZpc2lvbiI6MTAsImRhdGEiOnsiaWQiOiJyb290IiwidHlwZSI6Ik1hcCIsInZhbHVlIjp7ImJsYWgiOnsianNvbiI6ImFueXRoaW5nIn0sImtleSI6eyJqc29uIjoidmFsIn0sImtleTIiOnsianNvbiI6InZhbDIifX19fQ==","headers":{"date":"Thu, 08 Aug 2013 19:17:19 GMT","content-encoding":"gzip","x-goog-safety-encoding":"base64","server":"GSE","etag":"\"Q5ElJByAJoL0etObruYVPRipH1k/fDOlc7uypufY3ROxh-RtfV86Kmg\"","content-type":"text/plain; charset=UTF-8","cache-control":"private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform","x-goog-safety-content-type":"application/json","content-length":"183","expires":"Thu, 08 Aug 2013 19:17:19 GMT"},"status":200,"statusText":"OK"}}} 
      });
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="start();"></body></html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're looking into the issues with the client library, but for now I would recommend just making an XHR GET to the export URL:

```
var id = '{DOCUMENT ID}';
var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken()['access_token'];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/' + id + '/realtime?access_token=' + accessToken);
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.onerror = function() {
  // Handle error
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: This call now results in an error:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{FILE-ID}/realtime?{ACCES-TOKEN}. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3031' is therefore not allowed access.`

Answer (score 1):

If you are just running this inline as is, I think the problem is just that you need to wait for the contents to be saved before you do your get.

Add a [DocumentSaveStateChangedEvent](https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.DocumentSaveStateChangedEvent) listener to your document after making the change, and trigger realtimeget when both isPending and isSaving are false.

Looking at this code, a separate page load wouldn't do anything, since its creating a new document each time.

Comment: I pared down the code sample for brevity. The separate page load would skip `insertfile` and use the hardcoded `fileId` created from this code. The resulting realtime model root would see the {key: val} but it would still not show up in the export. I can post exact code if it would be clearer

Comment: You can change line 20 from

    `}, insertfile);`

to

    `}, function() { loadrealtime('FILEID-FROM-FIRST-RUN'); });`

for the second run

Comment: I edited to wait for the document to be done saving but the response is still empty

Comment: Ok, its a little hard to tell whats happening. If you post a full sample it might help.  Its expected that the local model might be different from the result of get() for some amount of time.  In a window where you have authorized for the file, try running this: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{YOUR_FILE_ID}/realtime?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}.  (You can get the token by calling gapi.auth.getToken())

Comment: Putting that url in the browser returns a 404. I am running this locally, could that be a problem?

Comment: If you are getting a 404 that means there does not exist a realtime document at the ID you provided that was created by the app that was used to create the access token you provided.  I'd double check that that is all correct.  Running locally shouldn't be a problem, so long as you are talking to the actual drive API.

Comment: Ok I was missing the www from the googleapis.com url. I get a response from /drive/v2/files{FILE_ID}/realtime?access_token={TOKEN} and it contains the correct contents of the document. However, the response to the `gapi.client.drive.realtime.get({'fileId': FILE_ID}).execute` is still empty. The body of the response is `[{"id": "gapiRpc","result": {}}]`

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in the javascript client for this particular method.  We are looking into it.